# Perforce shelve other users files as super user

Tags: perforce

I believe perforce super users can shelve other users' workspace files. How is this done?

I believe this would be done with `p4 shelve` but I'm not sure if it's possible to do it on another user's machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible if you have direct access to the other user's machine, in which case you can do it by logging in as a superuser, logging in as them using the `p4 login USERNAME` superuser command, and running the shelve command as normal.  Remember to `p4 logout` your superuser account when you're done!

The Perforce server does not have any way to initiate a connection to a client and gain access to data that exists only in a client workspace (i.e. opened files that have not yet been shelved or submitted).